# SQL result displaying data across different rows when results sould be across the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to replicate an excel spreadsheet in sql where information is in multiple columns but with only 2 rows that are different only in location number. In my sql, I have the correct information but it is split across multiple rows because there is another column in the sql that is not in the excel that I don't need. For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| $0.00 | $5.00 |
| $10.00 | $0.00 |

$5.00 and $10.00 should be in the same row but because there is a column C that sorts these two values differently they are not. I have not selected this column C so it is not in the output.

How can I get these values to be on one row?

I have tried using the `DISTINCT` keyword but because these two rows technically aren't distinct it isn't working

Comment: Sorting your data won't change anything you sort *rows* not columns. If $5.00 and $10.00 are meant to be in the same row then when you `INSERT`ed the data the data was wrong. You need correct the data, with an `UPDATE`, or clear the table and correcting `INSERT` the data.

Comment: What is in Column C for these two rows?

Comment: Difficult to say what's happening when there's no T-SQL code nor sample data. Are you attempting to use a `PIVOT` operation?

Comment: Edit your question and show a sample of your data, the code you are currently trying and the expected outcome based on the sample data.